# Angular11 Routing and Scroll to anchor

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, routes, anchor

Hi all I'm new with Angular,

I'm using `AngularCLI` and the Angular version is `11`. I have a simple `Bootstrap 4` template and I would like to reuse it for my `Angular 11` app.

Now the template is something like this:

```
<html>
 <header>
  ....
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
    <li>GROUP</li>
  </ul>
 </header>

 <main>
   <section id="group">
   ....................
   </section>

   <section id="contact>
   ....................
   </section>
 </main>
```

The template also has a `.js` file that, when user clicks on link, smoothly auto scroll to the relative anchor..

Now I put it inside Angular and everything works well but now I want to route to a component that will be fill with data comes from the server. Therefore I try to wrote:

```
<li><a href="#contact" (click)="scroll(contact)">CONTACT</a></li>
.....
.....

<section id="group">
   ..........
</section>
<section #contact id="contact>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</section>
```

In the component.ts:

```
scroll(el: HTMLElement) {
  el.scrollIntoView();
  el.setAttribute("class", "active");
}
```

but doesn't work because calling component refresh my page and I visualize the first section instead the second one.

I googlin around but there are a tons of possible solution and noone for my Angular version. what's the best way to do such a thing?

Anyway I think my Angular architecture is wrong.. maybe the `router-outlet` should contain the whole page and within the sections I will have to put something like `*ngIf` to see if there is data to display?

Thanks

Comment: did you import RouterModule in your app module?

Comment: Yes sure but the routing works is the autoscroll to anchor doesn't! If I manually scroll down I can see the my component insert at right place... but the call refresh my page and page return to the top header

Comment: can i ask you put your code in stackblitz ?

Comment: Yes sure I will do as soon as possible. I even put the standard bootstrap template to show the result I want to achieve